# Focus first UserControl child inside LayoutControl when it gets focus via tab

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, devexpress, focus

I have a UserControl (MyControl) that contains a LayoutControl which contains multiple editors (e.g. textedit). I put that Usercontrol inside a Layoutcontrol, that has multiple editors itself. So basically my hierarchy becomes as follows (names for further reference in quotations - "")

```
BaseControl{
    LayoutControl{ "OutsideLayout"
        ... multiple Controls "OutsideControls"
        UserControl{ "MyControl"
            LayoutControl{ "InsideLayout"
                TextEdit "StreetEdit"
                ...multiple Controls "InsideControls"
                TextEdit "LandEdit"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I tab through the *OutsideControls*, everything is fine. Once I've reached the last in line, the next tab will bring me to *MyControl* and by that directly to *StreetEdit*. I tab further, through the *InsideControls* and reach *LandEdit*. When I tab out of *LandEdit*, I reach the first *OutsideControl*, so basically where I started.

Everything as expected so far, here comes my problem:

If I tab through again, and tab into *MyControl*, this time, instead of focusing *StreetEdit*, it will focus *LandEdit*.

My question becomes: is it possible to focus *StreetEdit* when *MyControl* gets stepped into via tab?

I tried the Enter-Event but there are two problems with it. First, I don't want it to fire when I click a specific control and Enter-Event doesn't take EventArgs that would tell me the cause to differentiate. Second, somehow using something like *StreetEdit.Focus()* does not work. Can anyone explain why that is?

### Update (semi-solution)

I found a solution myself, but it is neither what I hoped, nor what I was looking for.

The *LayoutControl* has *OptionsFocus*, which has a property called *EnableAutoTabOrder*. All I did was set it to false. Now everything works as I wanted but not exactly the way I wanted. LayoutControl seems to provide a feature where it automatically manages tab order, which would be a nice thing to have, but with the solution I came up with now, that feature is disabled and I need to manage the tab order manually.

So I am still looking for a solution where this feature is not disabled *and* I get my desired result.

Comment: Have you checked tab order of the controls?

Comment: Tab order was right but there was, and still to some part is, another problem. Please check out my Update to this question.